# Can't create tempfile in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating Line Bot using Flask and trying to save image with code below

```
@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=ImageMessage)
def handle_image_message(event):
    count = 0
    message_content = line_bot_api.get_message_content(event.message.id)
    img_tmp = mktemp(dir=r'C:\Users\Suppavich\Desktop',prefix='img-',suffix='.jpg')
    f = open(img_tmp,'wb')
    for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
         f.write(chunk)
    print('success')
    print(f.name)
    f.close()
```

But mktemp() doesn't really create empty file on desktop as expected, so an error occured when trying to open img_tmp.

And it does happen the same for NamedTemporaryFile() as well

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Suppavich\\Desktop/img-0fjr9rhs.jpg'
```

...

So, Can anyone explain how "creating files" works with flask? because it can create files normally not using flask.

Thanks in advance and sorry for a newbie question

Comment: The created path of the tempfile looks weird. It has slashes and backslashes. On which OS are you and how do you run flask?

Comment: I'm running on Windows 10 and I kinda follow this example : [link](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/blob/master/examples/flask-kitchensink/app.py). Not sure what you mean how I run flask. Sorry @KlausD.

Comment: and if I run mktemp outside of (@)app.route or (@)handler, it creates file normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the tempfile module for this ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html )

```
import tempfile

@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=ImageMessage)
def handle_image_message(event):
    count = 0
    message_content = line_bot_api.get_message_content(event.message.id)

    with tempfile.TemporaryFile(dir='your_path', suffix='.jpg', prefix='img-') as fp:
        for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
             fp.write(chunk)
    print('success')
```

Comment: I tried using this : f = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb+', dir=static_tmp_path,delete=False) and I printed f.name 
and it returned /app/static/tmp/tmptcip7smc. But no such file is really created in that dir.